# RoomDatabse with Unique field, how to handle when values are the same?

Tags: android, database

In my `RoomDatabase`, there is field call **user_name**, it is unique.
When `save_button` is pressed how to check if **user_name** already exists?
If exists then I want to show `AlertDialog` which will inform the user.
I can create Arraylist with names only and before save it compare the values (from edittext with database), but I am looking for more efficient sollution.
I mean maybe `try/catch` instruction will help? If already exists then I can handle the error.

Comment: I am a noob with android but you can use OnConflictStrategy.ABORT anotation, I think then you can use a try catch

Comment: This will help you, just use onConflictStrategy by replacing or updating, based on user need from the dialog that you will show after testing for the existence of the row(create a simple query for that). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916388/android-room-inserts-duplicate-entities

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in your database which will check if the user has already existed in the database.

For example

@Query("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE user_name=:name")
fun isUserExists(name: String): User?

and check is function will return some value.
Or you can write a boolean SQL query to check if the user already existed

Comment: Ok. What do you think about use @Transaction. Here I just found an example (with 80 votes up) stackoverflow.com/questions/45677230/…
Problem is that I have interface and must use static it is ok?
So how to pass returned value (of example that I found) to my activity?

Comment: Can you show me your example in Java code please, beacuse I don't know nothing about Kotlin.        

Also boolean SQL query is interesting, but I can't imagine how to do that,       

If I think good,  boolean type return value  must be in all classes that are part of RoomDatabase like ViewModel, REPOSITORY.      

If you don't have time, only show your answer in java code thanks :D

Comment: @Query("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE user_name=:name")                   
public User isUserExists(String name)

Comment: Code works fine, but I have a small problem, How to use it with AsyncTask? Beacuse now my code execute in MainUI Thread. If I put it to AsyncTask the boolean value returns null beacuse it doesn't wait for AsyncTask. Line where I put new data is execute immediately after line where I check is name exists.